# csv field matching in where

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have in a category field that has csv for example 1,3,5 and i want to match against other categories in a table say (1,2,3,4), at the moment it uses a in cluase but this doesnt work when there are multiple categories.

```
Job.jobcategory_alias in (SELECT p_alias FROM job_categories WHERE p_id = 10225 or p_parent_id = 10225 or p_id = 10237 or p_parent_id = 10237)
```

it will work if jobcategory_alias has just one value like 1 but fail if it has two values like 1,2 comma seperated.

I cant change the structure of the database.

How can i write a query to match multiple categories?

Comment: Fix you data model so you are not storing comma-delimited lists in string columns.

Comment: i didnt design the table and as i said i cant change the structure

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_in_set()`:

```
find_in_set(Job.jobcategory_alias,
            (SELECT p_alias
             FROM job_categories
             WHERE p_id IN (10225, 10237) OR p_parent_id IN (10225, 10237)
            )
           ) > 0
```

This assumes that the subquery returns at most one row.

Comment: In my case the subquery returns multiple rows

Comment: I used GROUP_CONCAT to get into one row. Does find_in_set work with multiple values for the first parameter?, ive only seen examples for a single value

Comment: For example this returns 0, select find_in_set('a,b','a,b,c,d');

Comment: Is it not possible then ? Too hard a challenge

Comment: @tsukimi . . . Not really too big a challenge.  It is just much, much, much better to change the data structure.

Comment: so what would you suggest without changing the data structure, i have told them i would like to change the data structure but for now its not possibility , i am also curious how to do it, to see what work can be avoided with proper data structure